# Many to Many Relationsship, multiple input

Tags: laravel, tags, many-to-many

I've spent the last hours to find a solution, but have not found any. I use Laravel and have a many to many relationship between interest and user and between interest and itags.

My controller works, but the tags are not saved. I always get this error message:

> SQLSTATE [42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table does not
>   exist (SQL: select * from `itag` where (`itag` = test) limit 1)

A tag should only be saved in the database if it has not been saved yet. If the xyz is already stored, the already saved tag should be saved in the relationship for interest.
how can i save several tags and the relationship to interest?

this is my Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|min:3|max:15',
        'itag' => 'required'
    ]);

    $interest = new Interest();
    $interest->name = $request->name;

    $interest->save();

    if($interest)
    {
        $itagNames = explode(',' ,$request->get('itag'));
        $itagIds = [];
        foreach($itagNames as $itagName)
        {
            //$interest->tags()->create(['itag'=>$tagName]);
            //Or to take care of avoiding duplication of Tag
            //you could substitute the above line as
            $itag = Itag::firstOrCreate(['itag'=>$itagName]);
            if($itag)
            {
                $itagIds[] = $itag->id;
            }

        }
        $interest->itags()->sync($itagIds);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    $interest->user()->sync($user);


    return back()->with('success', lang::get('messages.newinterest'));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to get. I don't understand you.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: the message clearly states the table doesn't exist

Comment: Well, Laravel tells you that you table doesn't exists. Did you prepared migration for it?

Comment: Many to Many relationships require 3 tables how many tables do you have? Also it looks like you might want ManyThrough https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through You have a User->Interests->Tags relationship